# I can't install sailfin SIP Servlet in Netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, sip

I downloaded sailfin SIP .jar and extract jar file.

I go to Plug in > Available Plugin and click Add plugin button by installing them from the lib/tools/netbeans subdirectory of a SailFin.

Netbeans show SIP plugin for install. but I can install all of SIP plugin except SIP Project.

When I select SIP Project and install it show error can't install. So I'm not able to install SIP Project but when I create new project I can't find SIP category. please help me.

How to install SIPServlet in Netbeans6.9?

Answer (score 0):

After Oracle acquisition of Sun MicroSytems the Sailfin project is no longer active, I invite you to try another open source container called [Mobicents SIP Servlets](http://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/)